# Second level inclusion

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a function that includes another scripts:

```
function include-function($fileName)
{   
    .$fileName
}
```

I store this function in another script

From my main script I want to first include this script and then include another script:

```
."c:\1.ps1"                          #include first file
include-function "c:\2.ps1"          #call function to include other functions
xtest "bbb"                          #function from 2.ps1 that should be included
```

The problem is that function xtest from 2.ps1 is not visible in main script, it's only visible in scope of include-function. Is there a way to pass xtest to main script?

My include function doesn't realy load file (it gets it as string from API), so I can't call it directly from main script. As a workaround I just changed include-function to return me contents of a file and then from main script I call Invoke-Expression (include-function "c:\2.ps1")

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is the scope of your vars and function if in `2.ps1`, you declare your vars and functions as globals they will be visible in the global scope.

Exemple of 2.ps1 :

```
$global:Var2="Coucou"

function global:Test2 ([string]$Param)
{
  write-host $Param $Param
}
```

usage `test.ps1`:

```
function include-function($fileName)
{   
    .$fileName
}

Clear-Host

include-function "c:\silogix\2.ps1" 

Test2 "Hello"
```

gives :

```
Hello Hello
```

---

As you tag your question in PowerShell V2.0 you'd better have a look to modules. using module will end in a best structured programmation see [about_Modules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819458.aspx).